# Polymer 0.8 support for <table>?

Tags: polymer

The Polymer 0.8 [announcement page](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/#templating-features) states that there will be "Support for parser-challenged elements like `<table>`, `<select>`, etc.".

Is this referring to [the issues](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/resources/faq.html#option-tr) IE has with nesting `<table>` with `<template>`?

Comment: Yes :) IE has problems with `<template>` existing as a child of those elements.

Comment: @ebidel Maybe you could write up an answer that explains how the fix works/is different from the current situation?